# Visual Studio Extension: Is it possible to reuse existing Visual Studio Icons?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I have written my own Visual Studio 2015 extension and I'm wondering, if it is possible to use the standard visual studio icons for some general usecases (like search, case sensitive, start/stop, etc.)

Comment: You can download the icons in the [Visual Studio Image Library](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new Visual Studio [Image Service and Image Catalog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt628927.aspx) introduced in Visual Studio 2015 you can reuse standard VS icons with correct DPI scaling and theming in your extension.